# Add new columns to Pandas DF, performing basic maths equation for each row to determine values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So, I'm using Python 3.7 and performing a data report using Jupyter Notebooks. I have a dataframe, floridaDtFinal, which has the following columns:

```
State                                                object
County                                               object
Candidate                                            object
Total Votes                                           int64
County Vote Percentage                              float64
White Alone                                         float64
Black or African American Alone                     float64
American Indian and Alaska Native Alone             float64
Asian Alone                                         float64
Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander Alone    float64
Some Other Race Alone                               float64
Two or More Races                                   float64
Hispanic or Latino                                  float64
Hispanic or Latino (Mexican)                        float64
Hispanic or Latino (Puerto Rican)                   float64
Hispanic or Latino (Cuban)                          float64
Hispanic or Latino (Other Hispanic or Latino)       float64
Total Population                                    float64
dtype: object
```

I wish to add additional columns for each of the ethnicities listed. Values for each of the enthnicity columns are Census population values. The additional column and value I'd like to add would be a percentage of Total Population for that County, for each ethnicity. So, 'White Alone Percent', 'Black or African American Alone Percent' etc.

The rows in my DF are each County in the respective State.

[image: Pandas DF demonstrating layout]

I know I could essentially do something like this for each column value:

```
floridaDtFinal['White Alone Percent'] = 100 / floridaDtFinal['Total Population'] * floridaDtFinal['White Alone']
```

But I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to apply the calculation to every ethnicity in the list, without manually typing it.

I realise that typing this out has likely taken longer than manually typing it but I'm curious now and would love to know how I would go about performing it. Simply adding 'Percent' to the end of each and performing the calculation for the entire column.

I have performed searches but most results are based around creating column values based on list values, rather than column headers themselves.

Edit: Some sample dataframe as text.

```
{'State': {0: 'Florida',
  1: 'Florida',
  2: 'Florida',
  3: 'Florida',
  4: 'Florida'},
 'County': {0: 'Holmes County',
  1: 'Lafayette County',
  2: 'Baker County',
  3: 'Dixie County',
  4: 'Union County'},
 'Candidate': {0: 'Donald Trump',
  1: 'Donald Trump',
  2: 'Donald Trump',
  3: 'Donald Trump',
  4: 'Donald Trump'},
 'Total Votes': {0: 8080, 1: 3128, 2: 11911, 3: 6759, 4: 5133},
 'County Vote Percentage': {0: 89.105,
  1: 85.511,
  2: 84.722,
  3: 82.76,
  4: 82.194},
 'White Alone': {0: 17237.0, 1: 6931.0, 2: 23279.0, 3: 14333.0, 4: 11268.0},
 'Black or African American Alone': {0: 1356.0,
  1: 1394.0,
  2: 3824.0,
  3: 1474.0,
  4: 3359.0},
 'American Indian and Alaska Native Alone': {0: 266.0,
  1: 13.0,
  2: 144.0,
  3: 2.0,
  4: 116.0},
 'Asian Alone': {0: 131.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 173.0, 3: 38.0, 4: 93.0},
 'Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander Alone': {0: 60.0,
  1: 28.0,
  2: 10.0,
  3: 20.0,
  4: 10.0},
 'Some Other Race Alone': {0: 67.0, 1: 7.0, 2: 245.0, 3: 254.0, 4: 191.0},
 'Two or More Races': {0: 315.0, 1: 264.0, 2: 536.0, 3: 468.0, 4: 266.0},
 'Hispanic or Latino': {0: 546.0, 1: 1360.0, 2: 721.0, 3: 674.0, 4: 862.0},
 'Hispanic or Latino (Mexican)': {0: 248.0,
  1: 488.0,
  2: 133.0,
  3: 275.0,
  4: 217.0},
 'Hispanic or Latino (Puerto Rican)': {0: 120.0,
  1: 148.0,
  2: 149.0,
  3: 115.0,
  4: 249.0},
 'Hispanic or Latino (Cuban)': {0: 29.0,
  1: 568.0,
  2: 140.0,
  3: 147.0,
  4: 161.0},
 'Hispanic or Latino (Other Hispanic or Latino)': {0: 149.0,
  1: 156.0,
  2: 299.0,
  3: 137.0,
  4: 235.0},
 'Total Population': {0: 20524.0,
  1: 11357.0,
  2: 29653.0,
  3: 17937.0,
  4: 17027.0}
```

Comment: Will you update your question to include some of your sample dataframe as text (`df.head(5).to_dict()` for example)? Since we cannot copy from the image it makes it difficult to efficiently test out possible solutions. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Apologies. All done.

Comment: You say that most results you've found have involved "creating column values based on list values, rather than column headers themselves." Could you say more about what you mean? For what it's worth, I don't see a way of doing what you ask without having a predefined list of columns to modify. That's because you only want to modify a subset — the columns pertaining to race or ethnicity — and without a pre-existing list of columns, there's no straightforward way to identify that subset. (Without assuming the order of columns is fixed, that is — a dangerous assumption in my opinion!)

Comment: A predefined list was the solution. I thought that might have been the way to go but wasn't sure on how to apply it beyond that. I suppose assuming a fixed order could be risky. I could always create a subset by doing something like 'list(floridaDtFinal.columns.values)' to get the values, manually select the ones I want and store them as 'cols'?

In regards to my search. Everything I turned up seemed be a solution for taking a list of values and creating one additional new column, with the list values as the values for each row.

Solved now but thanks for your reply. An excellent point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like the following to create the new columns:

```
cols = floridaDtFinal.columns[5:17]
for col in cols:
    floridaDtFinal[f'{col} Percent'] = 100 / floridaDtFinal['Total Population'] * floridaDtFinal[col]
```

If you want to have the new columns come together with the original Ethnicity columns, you can further sort the column labels of the related columns (Ethnicity and Percent Columns) as follows:

```
header_col = ['State', 'County', 'Candidate', 'Total Votes', 'County Vote Percentage', 'Total Population']
floridaDtFinal = floridaDtFinal[header_col].join(floridaDtFinal.drop(columns=header_col).sort_index(axis=1))
```

Result:

```
     State            County     Candidate  Total Votes  County Vote Percentage  Total Population  American Indian and Alaska Native Alone  American Indian and Alaska Native Alone Percent  Asian Alone  Asian Alone Percent  Black or African American Alone  Black or African American Alone Percent  Hispanic or Latino  Hispanic or Latino (Cuban)  Hispanic or Latino (Cuban) Percent  Hispanic or Latino (Mexican)  Hispanic or Latino (Mexican) Percent  Hispanic or Latino (Other Hispanic or Latino)  Hispanic or Latino (Other Hispanic or Latino) Percent  Hispanic or Latino (Puerto Rican)  Hispanic or Latino (Puerto Rican) Percent  Hispanic or Latino Percent  Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander Alone  Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander Alone Percent  Some Other Race Alone  Some Other Race Alone Percent  Two or More Races  Two or More Races Percent  White Alone  White Alone Percent
1  Florida  Lafayette County  Donald Trump         3128                  85.511           11357.0                                     13.0                                         0.114467          0.0             0.000000                           1394.0                                12.274368              1360.0                       568.0                            5.001321                         488.0                              4.296909                                          156.0                                               1.373602                              148.0                                   1.303161                   11.974993                                              28.0                                                  0.246544                    7.0                       0.061636              264.0                   2.324558       6931.0            61.028441
2  Florida      Baker County  Donald Trump        11911                  84.722           29653.0                                    144.0                                         0.485617        173.0             0.583415                           3824.0                                12.895828               721.0                       140.0                            0.472128                         133.0                              0.448521                                          299.0                                               1.008330                              149.0                                   0.502479                    2.431457                                              10.0                                                  0.033723                  245.0                       0.826223              536.0                   1.807574      23279.0            78.504704
3  Florida      Dixie County  Donald Trump         6759                  82.760           17937.0                                      2.0                                         0.011150         38.0             0.211853                           1474.0                                 8.217651               674.0                       147.0                            0.819535                         275.0                              1.533144                                          137.0                                               0.763784                              115.0                                   0.641133                    3.757596                                              20.0                                                  0.111501                  254.0                       1.416067              468.0                   2.609132      14333.0            79.907454
4  Florida      Union County  Donald Trump         5133                  82.194           17027.0                                    116.0                                         0.681271         93.0             0.546191                           3359.0                                19.727492               862.0                       161.0                            0.945557                         217.0                              1.274446                                          235.0                                               1.380161                              249.0                                   1.462383                    5.062548                                              10.0                                                  0.058730                  191.0                       1.121748              266.0                   1.562225      11268.0            66.177248
0      NaN     Holmes County  Donald Trump         8080                  89.105           20524.0                                    266.0                                         1.296044        131.0             0.638277                           1356.0                                 6.606899               546.0                        29.0                            0.141298                         248.0                              1.208341                                          149.0                                               0.725979                              120.0                                   0.584681                    2.660300                                              60.0                                                  0.292341                   67.0                       0.326447              315.0                   1.534789      17237.0            83.984603
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: @obeskenobes  If you want the new columns to come together with the original Ethnicity  columns, please find my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could start y listing all ethnicity within you dataframe and then loop over all ethinicities :

```py
ethinities = floridaDtFinal.columns[5:17]

for ethinicty in ethnicities:
    floridaDtFinal[f"{ethnicity} Percent"] = 100 / floridaDtFinal['Total Population'] * floridaDtFinal[ethnicity]
```

Comment: Thank you. I was very close but that's so helpful. Exactly what I needed! Albeit with a few minor spelling mistakes. But the structure was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the final table with a percentage table obtained by using [pandas.multiply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html)

```
percentage_table = 100 / floridaDtFinal.iloc[:, 5:17].multiply(floridaDtFinal['Total Population'], axis='index')

floridaDtFinal.join(percentage_table, rsuffix=' Percent')
```